# review-suspension appeal - misunderstanding the requires editing option

Tags: discussion, status-completed, review-suspension

I have been suspended from reviewing for more than a month now.

I do not object the suspension at all and I am really sorry for all the damage that was done to the community because of my unacceptable mistake. The problem was that I had totally misunderstood the meaning of "requires editing" in the triage queue.

I am sorry for this mistake, but please keep in mind that I never got any warning that I was making this mistake. I got review suspended before this too but there was never any message so I thought that was just because I was reviewing too quickly.

I just thought I would post this to say that I have learned my lesson and I would be happy if the suspension is lifted so I can continue to contribute to the community and make some of my wrongs right.

Here is the message I get:

> You’ve been suspended from reviewing. You will be able to review again on Jan 4 '21 at 13:53.
> Your reviews on [triage/25651936](//stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25651936), [triage/25653107](//stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25653107), [triage/25652555](//stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25652555), [triage/25651137](//stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25651137), [triage/25652478](//stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25652478), [triage/25937540](//stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25937540), [triage/25934100](//stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25934100), [triage/25936869](//stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25936869), [triage/25936434](//stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25936434), [triage/25937289](//stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25937289), [triage/25936764](//stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25936764), [triage/25937633](//stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25937633), [triage/25937300](//stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25937300), etc., wasn't helpful. The "Requires Editing" option should only be used when other community users (like you) are able to edit/format an already answerable question into a better shape. If a question can be closed or can only be improved/clarified by the question asker, please use the "Unsalvageable" option instead. If in doubt always use the "Skip" option. For more information, see Getting banned from Triage reviews and How does the Triage queue work?.

Comment: You say you misunderstood the meaning, so now you understand it, what is it intended to mean?

Comment: Multiple month long suspensions happen due to multiple incorrect reviews not just one.  A moderator will want you to indicate your incorrect choice and specify what the correct choice should have been.

Comment: @SecurityHound yes. I have done many many wrong reviews all for the same reason. and I was suspended many times but It was never explained to me that I was being suspended because of this. I thought it was rate limiting because I did so many reviews in one day.

Comment: @Nick I thought requires editing is somehow shown to the post author, telling them that they should edit their question. I think I actually commented for them many times asking them to clarify their question. I thought It was for when someone had a valid question but didn't explain themselves good enough or didn't provide enough information. But now I understand that it means that the post is complete but needs some editorial cleanup from other users and not the author.

Comment: Actually I got banned in April but I never got any notice until now. before I was only told that I was banned and I didn't really know why until now.

Comment: My suggestion is answer this question, and specify what the correct action should have been to a handful of your reviews, to show you actually understand you selected the incorrect option.  Your original question made the incorrect claim that this was about a single review.  You still make the incorrect unintentional claim you were not warned or suspended before by the way.  The fact you were suspended until January 2021 back in April, means the number of reviews you got wrong, were numerous

Comment: @SecurityHound by "mistake" I meant the misunderstanding, I didn't mean that it was one erroneous review. I'm sorry if I didn't make that clear enough.

Comment: @SecurityHound You mean I should go throught the erroneous reviews in an answer under this meta post and explain that I have understood right? sure. I will do that in a few hours. thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Based on the number of bad reviews, don’t do every single one, do a handful.  Hopefully, by doing this, you show that you understand what your mistakes were specifically

Answer (score 1):

1. triage/25651936 Was Unsalvageable because the OP did not specify enough information for us to be able to reproduce their problem.
2. triage/25653107 Was Unsalvageable because "grep" does not appear on the first line and as such it is not possible to understand what the OP is talking about unless they edit their question and add more information.
3. triage/25651137 Was Unsalvageable beacuse PjoterS has asked some questions, the answers to which were needed for anyone to be able to answer that question but the OP was not answering to their comment or editing their question to include the needed information.
4. triage/25937540 Was Unsalvageable because it is just a line of code and a random sentence, no question is asked. The OP should edit this question to add more information.
5. triage/25934100 Was Unsalvageable because the OP did not say what was their problem. they just mentioned their goal and put a code. I commented that they had to edit their question and add their code in the question. I should have said that they should also explain to us what their problem actually is.
6. triage/25936869 Was Unsalvageable because the OP had not said what they had already tried and they had not put enough effort themselves. I properly commented this for them but I thought this was what requires editing meant.
7. triage/25937289 Was Unsalvageable because the OP had not said what they had already tried and they had just mentioned many things that they wanted to do but Stackoverflow is not a coding service and they should put enough effort and ask our help when they run into a specific, clear, well defined problem.
8. triage/25937633 Was Unsalvageable because the OP had not put enough effort.
9. triage/25936764 I had properly commented their problem but chose the wrong option due to my misunderstanding.

Please let me know if I should add more items.

Comment: @HarshalParekh This was a moderator imposed suspension of review queues. This is the _only_ way to get it lifted early, and it has been.